# Need help to move ELB from one account to other

Tags: amazon-web-services

Could someone please let me know how could i move an ELB from one account to other. I know that to move instances we usually take ami backup and give permissions but how could I move an ELB?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot move an ELB. Just copy the configuration. (That's also what you're doing with the EC2 instance.)

Comment: For instances I take AMI backup and restore in other account but for ELB how could I copy the conf or take backup. Do you mean that I need to create the load balancer with same conf in my target account. Could you please provide me with any document available to copy ELB from one account to other

Comment: You can't backup an ELB, so there is nothing for you to move to the new account. You just need to create an ELB on the new account and copy all the settings over from the old ELB. If you just open them in two browser tabs and view them side-by-side this would only take a few minutes. If you want to start backing up this sort of configuration then you could look into using something like CloudFormation or Teraform, but that's a much more advanced topic.